# imagecopy doesn't work all the time

Tags: php, gd

I'm having an issue with `imagecopy` certain images on the `$url` variable will not appear even though there both `PNG` on the working and not working examples. The `$local` variable loads transparent images from the server and `$url` variable loads from a remote server. I have inculded a test transparent image for `$local`.

**Working:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$url = imagecreatefrompng("url_removed.png");
$local = imagecreatefrompng("http://url_removed.png");
imagecopy($url, $local, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
imagepng($url);
imagedestroy($url);
imagedestroy($local);
?>
```

**Not working:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$url = imagecreatefrompng("url_removed.png");
$local = imagecreatefrompng("http://url_removed.png");
imagecopy($url, $local, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
imagepng($url);
imagedestroy($url);
imagedestroy($local);
?>
```

I have even tried `imagecreatestring` with `file_get_contents` and that works also but certain `PNG` images it doesn't work just like with `imagecreatefrompng`

After all that said in done, I think it has something to do with `imagecopy`.... what can I do to fix this or is there another simple way of doing this?

Comment: Feels like `find the differences between the two codes` ^_^

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran the codes are exact but the URL path is different. :)

Comment: are you willing to copy part of image or whole image merge?

Comment: @xnome I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: i tested both codes on my server, both codes above produce http://i.imgur.com/0A81XrP.png, which is the same, trying to modify it with imagecopymerge(), it produce error

Comment: @xnome let me test them again may of been a copy and paste fail.

Comment: @xnome I have updated the question with the outputs I get. The first one works, the second one only shows the transparent image, which is the problem I'm having with only certain `png` images.

Comment: @chillers, we use the same server configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd test with both codes, and it works

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$url = imagecreatefrompng("http://i.imgur.com/F7Jpk9y.png");
$local = imagecreatefrompng("http://i.imgur.com/0A81XrP.png");
// use imagecopymerge instead and set the copied image opacity to 50
imagecopymerge($url, $local, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 64,50); 
imagepng($url);
imagedestroy($url);
imagedestroy($local);
?>
```

output https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqPYe.jpg

Comment: I tried that already but to get the transparent image to work correctly without it turning the image black with 100% opacity, I had to use `imagecopy` :)

Comment: is there a file type or a certain way of saving PNG to work with transparent images for the local image I can save that will work with 100% opacity?

Comment: http://imgur.com/1XZKZ8f, i think imagecopy function does not support image transparency, sometimes i get same problem too, but quickly solved, the problem may came from the x, y axis, but your code and both images are nothing wrong

Comment: I would at least like to keep the `URL` image the same color depth as it will be needed to match other images but of course the `local` image is to obscure it.

Comment: this is my libPNG Version 1.2.46, i tested to set the opacity to 100% and got it turn black :(, and it's weird, the original X image have a transparent background

Comment: yea same problem with `imagecopymerge` but I did find something on `imagecopyresampled` and so far it works but having trouble re-sizing everything.

Comment: After some testing your method will work, The point of local image will be to obscure the image and this will still achive what I'm looking for thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An option could be analyzing the error file inside php `error/warnings logs`:

```
xampp > apache > logs > error.txt
```

There you can find what caused the error during the image load.