# Outputting an Image with PHP

Tags: php, image

What I'm trying to do is take 2 images and combine them to output a single image. When I try to run my script I get a broken image icon and nothing else.

```
<?php
  header( "Content-type: image/png" );
  $img1 = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://www.refaim.com/images/maleCharacter.jpg');
  $img3 = imagecreatefrompng('http://www.refaim.com/images/leafswordleft.png');

  $x1 = imagesx($img1);
  $y1 = imagesy($img1);
  $x2 = imagesx($img3);
  $y2 = imagesy($img3);
  imagecopyresampled(
    $img1, $img3,
    7, 135, 0, 0,
    50, 50,
    $x2, $y2);
  imagepng($img1);
?>
```

I've tried all of the other suggestions on other topics, but none of them worked. Also, if I try to call the file in an  tag I still get a broken image.

Comment: Does it work if you output an image witout changing it first?

Comment: Do you want to make a download image link??

Comment: Atle, it works if I save it to an outside file, I'll try and see if it works without changing. 
Edit: even with no manipulation I get the broken image box.
Bizzon, I don't want an image link, I just want to output the image on the same page if possible, if not then by calling the script in an image tag. Something like this <img src="imageScript.php" />

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720119/imagecopy-doesnt-work-all-the-time/undefined, this question similiar to the last post i answered

Comment: @xnome I tried the imagecopymerge and I still get a broken image, starting to think it may have something to do with my PHP settings, could that be a problem?

Comment: @user2243125 i see no error from your code, this is [your image](http://imgur.com/MgOFThM) produced from that code, please use **`vardump(gd_info())`** to verify  currently installed GD library

Comment: @xnome my GD version is 2.0.34 compatible.
How did you go about outputting the image? For me it only works if I save it to a separate file, I can't seem to output the image just by calling <img src="script.php" />.

Comment: i did it without modifying your code, unfortunately i've erase your code in my test server, but it's the same as yours, no error

Comment: the most funny thing for me is there are many complaining about phpGDlib, i actually find error because of own error, phpGDlib did some error in the past version, but i rarely found one nowadays

Comment: @xnome I got it to work, the problem was that I didn't notice I opened it up originally as an HTML file so all the HTML markup was still on the page, super silly mistake haha. Thanks for the help.

Comment: see...? i told you, you're always welcome [PS] i don't know how to close this question as `SOLVED` :P